# How to order articles by both quality score and publish date?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I have a database that contains articles with pre-calculated quality scores ranging from 0 to 10 (with 10 being best quality) and each article has a published date.

Here is an example database schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `score` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `published` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=357 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How can I order the articles that are the newest and best scored?

For example, the following doesn't work because it places all the scored `10` articles first even if they are very old. The newest scored `9` article appears after all the `10`s.

```
 SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY score DESC, published DESC;
```

If I order by published first, then the score value has no effect because all the published times are unique.

```
 SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY published DESC, score DESC;
```

I need to somehow order these records so that higher scored articles come first, but place them lower in the list the older they get.

Here is some quick sample data I made.

```
INSERT INTO `articles` (`title`, `content`, `score`, `published`) VALUES ('Test', 'Test', '10', '2013-07-09 21:25:43');
INSERT INTO `articles` (`title`, `content`, `score`, `published`) VALUES ('Test', 'Test', '5', '2013-07-08 13:34:12');
INSERT INTO `articles` (`title`, `content`, `score`, `published`) VALUES ('Test', 'Test', '10', '2013-07-07 20:17:02');
INSERT INTO `articles` (`title`, `content`, `score`, `published`) VALUES ('Test', 'Test', '9', '2013-02-12 10:32:11');
INSERT INTO `articles` (`title`, `content`, `score`, `published`) VALUES ('Test', 'Test', '10', '2006-01-01 01:05:13');
```

With that date if you order by `SCORE DESC, published DESC` then I get article dated `2006-01-01` appearing before article scored as `9` but it has an earlier date.

What the means is this old article remains on the front page of the website, when newer articles scored `9` are just as worthy of being there.

Comment: can you give sample data?

Comment: not sure I understand the question. it seems the 1st query works as what you want. if you want to consider both score and time at the same time for ranking, one way is to give them a weight for rank, i.e. score weight = 0.7, time weight = 0.3, then rank. again, not sure what you want, maybe give an example with data will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need some weighting for this. This one is based on the [Hacker News Algorithm](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19574).

```
SELECT *,
(score/power(((NOW()-published)/60)/60,1.8)) as rank
FROM posts ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

Comment: Is this some sort of ranking algorithm?

Comment: Changed to use day weighting, unless your articles update often enough that by hours is more important.

Comment: @MarkM oh could you change it back. The articles are updated every few minutes.

Comment: Oh, okay, changed it back then.

Answer (score 4):

You need to calculate a relevance score based on those two parameters.  How such a relevance score is calculated will depend on how you wish for the two metrics to relate (e.g. the rate at which older articles become less interesting).

Suppose one defined a [stored function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-routines.html) `relevance(score TINYINT UNSIGNED, published DATE) RETURNS INT`, then one might simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY relevance(score, published)
```

Of course, rather than defining a stored function, one could simply express the calculation directly within the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: But I think this is way too adv for what he requires.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply order by date, not the full datetime then:

```
ORDER BY DATE(published) DESC, score DESC;
```

And of course you can set lower priority to date by rounding date to month or week or whatever.

Here is th [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2e89/2)

Comment: This groups articles by day. It's not really what I'm looking for. An article with a zero score will appear before a higher score of yesterday.